# Overlay two images of different types

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing, bitmap, drawing

I need to overlay the following images:

1. `System.Windows.Controls.Image` image1
2. `System.Drawing.Bitmap` image2;

I need the output to be of type `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`.

I thought of the following way: Convert image2 into a `Bitmap` and the overlay the two images using `System.Drawing.Graphics`, but I don't know how to convert image2.

Comment: what do you mean by overlay..? a image on the top of another..?

Comment: does using 2 image control will solve your problem..? i mean adding 2 images control to same grid will automatically overlay images right..?

Comment: i already have it this way, but how would i get the imageSource from the grid after overlaying?

Comment: i tried to build up a sample to overlay .. but i don't have images to test it.. can you send me images to bathineni.venkatesh@gmail.com to test my code

Comment: well what am doing is a part of a big project. Image1 is retrieved as the OS icon of a document, and Image2 is retrieved from Xaml that saves images as DrawingImage. For simplicity, u can google .png images and download any two images, save them on locally, then use them by reading from file.

Comment: @bathineni let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2017/discussion-between-strider007-and-bathineni)

Answer (score 1):

One option is overlaying the two items in a grid as suggested above and then using [this technique](http://dotbay.blogspot.com/2009/06/rendering-wpf-visuals-to-bitmap.html) to render the control to a bitmap file.

Alternatively, you could convert both files to a bitmap and loop over them using the following code (this code combines the images by layering bitmap2 on bitmap1, assuming any white values in bitmap2 are transparency values - you can change this blending condition by altering one line):

```
Bitmap bitmap1;
Bitmap bitmap2;
Bitmap result;
for(int x = 0; x<bitmap1.Width;x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y<bitmap1.Height;y++)
    {
        //condition for choosing which pixel to pick - based on how you want to overlay them (this code assumes white is transparent)
        if(bitmap2.GetPixel(x,y) == Colors.White)
        {
            result.SetPixel(x,y) = bitmap.GetPixel(x,y);
        }
        else
        {
            result.SetPixel(x,y) = bitmap2.GetPixel(x,y);
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you the Bitmap result, which you can then do whatever you want with.

The first option is faster, as it is accelerated by the WPF render code, however I've heard people have struggled to force the rendered bitmap to not output immediately to a file, so if you want it in memory without loading the file again it's not your best bet.

The second option gives you much more control over how the images are combined, but is potentially slower.